# How to correctly work with SQLite InMemory database in integration test

Tags: sqlite, xunit.net, asp.net-core-5.0

Because Entity framework does not support `_context.Database.EnsureDeleted();` when using SQLite InMemory database (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26707). My question is, how to properly reset the database within each test?

My WebApplicationFactory looks like this

```
 public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Web.Startup>
 {
     private SqliteConnection Connection;
     protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
     {
         // Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite needs to be installed.
         Connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
         Connection.Open();

         builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
         {
             // Unregister existing database service.
             var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext>));
             if (descriptor != null) services.Remove(descriptor);
             // Register new database service.
             services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Connection));
         });
     }
     protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
     {
         base.Dispose(disposing);
         Connection.Close();
     }
}
```

My test looks like this

```
 public class DFPLControllerTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
     {
         private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
         private readonly IServiceScope _scope;
    
         public DFPLControllerTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
         {           
             _scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();
             _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
         }
    
         [Fact]
         public async Task Import()
         {
             // Arrange
             // _context.Database.EnsureDeleted() // deleting current state of the database does not work here.
         }
    }
```

What should I call in each test (Fact method) to reset/empty the database? Or should I edit constructor of the test Controller class or WebApplicationFactory in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do currently is instead of

```
_context.Database.EnsureDeleted()
```

in each test, I call

```
 _context.RemoveRange(_context.TableFoo);
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'TableFoo';");

 _context.RemoveRange(_context.TableBar);
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'TableBar';");

 // ...

 _context.SaveChanges();
```

for all the database tables and after that I seed the data again.